# Definition of $\sigma - $finite

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have that a measure space is $\sigma - $finite if $\Omega = \cup_i^\infty E_i$ where the $E_i$ are measurable and $\mu(E_i) < \infty$.

Now, I am reading a proof, and it says that suppose a measure $\mu$ is $\sigma- $finite, then there exists $E_1 \subset E_2 \subset ...$ such that $\mu(E_i) < \infty $ and $\Omega = \cup_i^\infty E_i$. Could someone explain how this is equivalent to my definition, why are the $E_i$s all nested here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically three useful variants of the "$\sigma$-finite decomposition":

1. $E_i$ have no relation to each other
2. $E_i$ are increasing.
3. $E_i$ are disjoint.

It is clear that 2 implies 1 and 3 implies 1. 1 implies 2 because you can write $\Omega=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty F_k$ where $F_k=\bigcup_{i=1}^k E_i$. 1 implies 3 because you can write $\Omega=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty G_k$ where $G_k=E_k \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^{k-1} E_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Omega$ be $\sigma$-finite, and pick $E_1,E_2,\dots$ such that $\mu(E_i) < \infty$ and $\Omega = \cup E_i$. For $n \geq 1$, let $F_n = \cup_{i=1}^n E_i$. By construction, the $F_i$ are nested, each with finite measure, and $\cup F_i = \Omega$.